# Python Discord Bot @commands.has_any_role issue

Tags: python, discord, bots

So I want admins to have the ability to add roles to the list 'admin_roles'. My issue is when calling @commands.has_any_role(*admin_roles), it does not seem to look at anything that has been appended to the list.

Code -

```
admin_roles = []

@client.command()
@commands.has_any_role('Owner')
async def addadminrole(ctx, role):
    global admin_roles
    admin_roles.append(role)

@client.command()
@commands.has_any_role(*admin_roles)
async def setinfo(ctx, item, description):
    global desc
    if(item == 'desc'):
        desc = description
```

So when the code is run, I get the error discord.ext.commands.errors.MissingAnyRole: You are missing at least one of the required roles:

No matter how many things get appended to the list, the has_any_role doesn't check for them.

Answer (score 0):

A decorator is invoked once as soon as the module is imported, and then the function that gets called is whatever was provided by the decorator definition. The problem that you are facing is that you modify your global variable in the middle of your runtime, but this does not cause the decorator to be re-applied, and thus it uses the values from when it was invoked at import. Because `admin_roles` is an empty list at the time of module import, it will be passed as an empty list into `commands.has_any_role`. To achieve a similar level of functionality (though not the best), you can do something like:

```
from discord.ext.commands import MissingAnyRole, NoPrivateMessage
from discord.channel import DMChannel
@client.command()
async def setinfo(ctx, item, description):
    global admin_roles
    if isinstance(ctx.channel, DMChannel): #if this is a private message, roles do not apply.
        raise NoPrivateMessage
    if not len([role for role in ctx.author.roles if role in admin_roles]): # if the invoking Member has no roles in admin_roles, throw the same error as check_any_role
        raise MissingAnyRole
    global desc
    if(item == 'desc'):
        desc = description
```

Answer (score 0):

I found another way to solve this issue. I understand what was wrong with my initial code since admin_roles is never called before it is accessed. This is the code I used to circumvent my issue -

```
@client.command()
async def setinfo(ctx, item, description):
    global admin_roles
    global desc
    x = 0
    roles = [0]*len(admin_roles)
    while x < len(admin_roles):
        roles[x] = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name=admin_roles[x])
        if roles[x] in ctx.author.roles:
            if(item == 'desc'):
                desc = description
        x += 1
```