# discord.py command can only work for user with one of several role in a list

Tags: python, discord.py

I am currently building a discord bot using Discord py with one of its command can only be used by a user with one of several roles that I have set up.

Currently, I store all of the role name in a list since I also have a command to add new role to that list. This is a snippet of what I have right now

```py
role_name = ["Moderator"]

@bot.command(name='role',help='adding role for staff moderating role (admin only command)')
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def add_role(ctx, role):
    if role not in role_name:
        role_name.append(role)

    print(*role_name) #use case 1: when run this command to add 'mine' it print "Moderator mine"

@bot.command(name='add',help='Add channel, when you run this command, you must be in the channel ')
@commands.has_any_role(role_name)
async def add_channel(ctx):
    if ctx.channel.id not in channel_id:
        channel_id.append(ctx.channel.id)
```

I have double check on my account's role on discord and it already have Moderator role

[image]

However, when I run the command to test - this is what i got

`discord.ext.commands.errors.MissingAnyRole: You are missing at least one of the required roles: '['Moderator']'`

Is there any way to do what I want?

**/Edit:** Add the adding role to the role_name for the sake of clarity. I also have tried `",".join(role_name)` in `has_any_role()` however, I still get this issue `discord.ext.commands.errors.MissingAnyRole: You are missing at least one of the required roles: ''`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some extra research regarding the decorator. Apparently, based on this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/64544809/10467473 -

> A decorator is invoked once as soon as the module is imported, and
> then the function that gets called is whatever was provided by the
> decorator definition.

Therefore, I tried a different approach to check the role like how I wanted it to be and now it works perfectly fine! This is the method that I use.

```py
role_name=[]

@bot.command(name='role',help='adding role for staff moderating role (admin only command)')
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def add_role(ctx, role):
    if role not in role_name:
        role_name.append(role)

@bot.command(name='add',help='Add channel, when you run this command, you must be in the channel ')
async def add_channel(ctx):
    global role_name
    user_role = ctx.author.roles
    for rl in user_role:
        if (rl.name in role_name):
           if ctx.channel.id not in channel_id:
              channel_id.append(ctx.channel.id)
              break
```

Answer (score 1):

`has_any_role()` accepts `*items` and is looking for `str` or `int` objects. The list is read as a string `'["Moderator"]'`. You can check this by trying to rename your rolename as well.

A simple fix for this would be:
`@commands.has_any_role(*role_name)` for your bot from read the list as a string.

So it looks like this:

```py
role_name = ["Moderator"]

@bot.command(name='add',help='Add channel, when you run this command, you must be in the channel ')
@commands.has_any_role(*role_name)
async def add_channel(ctx):
    if ctx.channel.id not in channel_id:
        channel_id.append(ctx.channel.id)
```

Comment: I have tried using this solution, but it gives me this error `discord.ext.commands.errors.MissingAnyRole: You are missing at least one of the required roles: ` I decide to add the function that I have right now that add something to the role_name list

Comment: While this question doesn't answer my question but it manages to guide me on searching for the real answer. I able to find the answer from here https://stackoverflow.com/a/64544809/10467473